# Python SyntaxError when using open()

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

For some reason I keep getting a syntax error from my open statement:

```
def printStatsToFile():
    global dictionary
    statslines = []
    if dictionary=={}:
        createDictionary()
    for n in dictionary:
        statslines.append("Key = " + str(n) + "    Total number of words with " + str(n) + " characters = " + str(len(dictionary[n]))
    open(statsWords.dat, "w").writelines(statslines)
    print "Your stats are now available in statsWords.dat."
    mainFunction()
```

Here is the error:

```
tog:hw4 lukasolson$ python hw4_lukasolson.py
  File "hw4_lukasolson.py", line 61
    open(statsWords.dat, "w").writelines(statslines)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Oddly, when I comment out part of the code, everything works absolutely fine:

```
def printStatsToFile():
    statslines = []
    """
    global dictionary
    if dictionary=={}:
        createDictionary()
    for n in dictionary:
        statslines.append("Key = " + str(n) + "    Total number of words with " + str(n) + " characters = " + str(len(dictionary[n]))
    """
    open("statsWords.dat", "w").writelines(statslines)
    print "Your stats are now available in statsWords.dat."
    mainFunction()
```

And I am running python 2.7.6 so as far as I know, my syntax should be correct.

```
tog:hw4 lukasolson$ python
Python 2.7.6rc1 (v2.7.6rc1:4913d0e9be30+, Oct 27 2013, 20:52:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on the line above it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in `statsWords.dat` as a string.  Thus, the line should look like:

```
open("statsWords.dat", "w").writelines(statslines)
```

Comment: There would be a different type of error if that was what error python found.